# How to write an installer that also allows to run the software from CD

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I have an application that will be located on the CD-ROM and I need to make an installer for it, that will ask the user if he wants to run the application from the CD-ROM or install it on the hard drive, how can I do it with InnoSetup, is it even possible?

Comment: Wait, installer will ask the user if they want to run the application from CD ? That doesn't make much sense to me. Installer is, uhm, for installing, not for executing applications. That's what those (usually :-) colorful autorun applications are for. Or did I miss something ? Btw. you didn't said that; will that installer be on CD ?

Comment: @Close voters, **this is a programming question related to Inno Setup installer. It doesn't belong to Server Fault!** I'll delete this comment later on...

Comment: That's what the customer wants ;). So yes it will be all on the CD, so the end user could select if he wants to run it from CD or install the CD content to the hard drive.

Comment: Nothing more to say :-) Ok, now how do they imagine such installer ? For start, I would suggest to make a custom form with options to run or install which will be displayed as the very first thing and if the user press install, it will start the wizard. If they choose run option, the application will start and the setup will exit. What do you think (or what they might think) ?

Comment: @TLama: I'll avoid close-voting in response to your comment, but could this not be closed under "demonstrate a minimal understanding" due to lack of attempted solutions?

Comment: @halfer, yes of course, it could be. I just wanted to prevent migration to a different site caused by the "random" close voters. Thanks for your favour!

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example that uses [Tasks] to define a CD-ROM or Hard drive installation. The program file resides adjacent to the installer, i.e. on the CD-ROM. You start your application via the Startmenu shortcut which either points to the the CD-Rom or Hard drive depending upon which task option was selected. Hope this helps.

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
DefaultGroupName=My Program
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\MyProg.exe
Compression=lzma2
SolidCompression=yes
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Files]
;The MyProg.exe file shall reside in the same (cd-rom) folder as the Installer. It will only be installed if the Task option RunFromInstallation is checked.
Source: "{src}\MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: external; Tasks: RunFromInstallation;

[Icons]
;Depending upon which Task Option was selected the Start menu item points to either the installation folder or the installation (cd-rom) media 
Name: "{group}\My Program"; Filename: "{src}\MyProg.exe"; Tasks: RunFromExternalMedia;
Name: "{group}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; Tasks: RunFromInstallation;

[Tasks]
;In Task dialog user will be prompted to select the Deployment Method. Because of the Exclusive Flag only one of the options can be selected.
Name: RunFromExternalMedia; Description: "Run from: {src}";    GroupDescription: Deployment method:; Flags: exclusive;
Name: RunFromInstallation;  Description: "Install to: {app}";  GroupDescription: Deployment method:; Flags: exclusive;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own program that asks the user, and then runs the InnoSetup installer, if needed.

Alternatively, hook into the [InitializeSetup event](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm) and abort the installer, if needed.

Comment: own program != inno setup, I thought I could do that with InnoSetup

Comment: Sure you can, but there's a lot to clarify. Except the visual requirements; for instance, if that installation process will require elevation and running that application won't, wouldn't then be bothering to ask users for elevation when starting just the "autorun" screen ? For a vague question a vague answer.

Comment: I was going to add this as a separate answer, but it's basically the same as this one:  the "right way" to do this is to use Inno to write the installation part only, and then to use a separate "autorun" program to let the user choose between installing or running from disc.  Sure, it's possible to get Inno to do both jobs but it's really not what it's designed for and it's much cleaner to separate it.